# How to activate file and printer sharing from the command line on a French Windows system?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, file-sharing

I am trying to enable files and printer sharing from command line, after some Googling I found that the right command to achieve this:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=yes
```

This seems to be okay if the Windows language is English. However, in my French Windows this is the result from an administrative command prompt:

> Aucune règle ne correspond aux critères spécifiés.
>
> (English Translation: No rule matches the specified criteria)

I've also tried this command line:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Partage de fichiers et d'imprimantes" new enable=yes
```

But it didn't work as well and I get the same result as above.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the apostrophe character in the command line.

- The one that the keyboard displays is `'`
- But the correct one for firewall rule is `’`

So do a copy of a firewall rule title with that correct apostrophe character and then past it on a command shell.

Example:

- **Not Okay**: `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Partage de fichiers et d'imprimantes" new enable=no`
- **Okay**: `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Partage de fichiers et d’imprimantes" new enable=no`

The difference is between `d`  and  `imprimantes`.

It's not easy to script a batch with the correct apostrophe character. It returns an error. The apostrophe is correctly displayed in editor but misinterpreted on command prompt.

You can also use the keybooard input <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0146</kbd>, which will display the correct `’` character (found in the Windows characters map).

Topics related to:

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0810b2f9-87a8-42a5-ac15-4bc9b1e4ad90/single-quote-straight-apostrophe?forum=winRDc
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af88de35-0156-4a8a-8b04-16cf23c5d3fa/apostrophe-character-problem-with-net-group-command-or-listing-group-and-member-with-a-bat-script?forum=ITCG

On a command prompt, the two different apostrophe characters are displayed identically so it's not easy to found that this one character is messing up the entire command line, as displayed in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FuC4.png)

Answer (score 0):

"File and printer sharing" firewall group can be enabled regardless of Windows language version with:

1. netsh advfirewall with indirect string - index -28502 translates to name of the group (you can extract other available strings with indexes using eg. Nirsoft Resources Extract)

   ```
   netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="@FirewallAPI.dll,-28502" new enable=Yes
   ```
2. netsh firewall - deprecated since Windows Vista, but might be useful for Windows XP (no advfirewall or FirewallAPI.dll available)

   ```
   netsh firewall set service type=FileAndPrint mode=enable
   ```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to the above answer: Since you seem to speak/type English just fine, you can change the display language to English through the Control Panel (or I'm sure via PowerShell, I just don't know the command), run that or any other command you want, then change it back to French once you're done.

Comment: Please provide specifics on how to do what you describe. I personally know how to do it, but the author, clearly does not.  If you don't know the Powershell command, why do you mention, it **might be possible**?  If you don't know the command how do you know if it even exists? (again I know the answers to these questions I am asking, you should edit your answer, and improve your answer)